# Auto resizing div

Tags: css

Let's start with live example: http://makeshot.net/f/LX8Y2jH

You can zoom in and out the black image. There's navigation bar which width is 100%. After zooming in image `#nav` doesn't grow and stays on old size.

```
#nav{
width: 100%;
float: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #C9C9C9;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #ddd;
    position: relative; 
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
text-align: center; }
#nav li {
    list-style: none;
    display:inline-block; }
    #nav li a.special { 
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc; 
    }
        #nav li a:hover.special { 

    }
#nav li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 5px;
     font-size: 13px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc; }
#nav li a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000; 
    -moz-border-radius: 3px; -webkit-border-radius: 3px; -khtml-border-radius: 3px; border-radius: 3px; }
```

Comment: I don't really understand, since I see everything grow, the only thing that's not getting bigger is the black box since it's 100%

Comment: This is how it looks for me after zoomin and scrolling to right: http://imgur.com/QLNS445.png And I want upper navigation box to fit the screen all the time.

Comment: On what browser was the screenshot taken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this to your css

```
#nav{position:fixed;}
```

Comment: Tried it several times but haven't noticed that there's `position: relative;` too.